# It's hard to identify deleted questions from the review history on Meta

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, meta

On a review history page here on meta (say of the [close votes queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history)), the titles of non-deleted questions don't stand out at all:

> [image]

Comparing that to the same page on the main site, the non-deleted question titles stand out a lot more:

> [image: SO review history]

Deleted questions are shown in that grey color, wheras questions that aren't deleted are shown in a blue. Since the link color here on meta is red-ish, I'd assume that's what the non-deleted questions should show up as. Could this please be fixed?

Comment: Clearly the solution is to become a moderator so they're just all linkified regardless...

Comment: @animuson Clearly. SE should just [make us mods](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=13087095#13087095).

Comment: you only need 10k rep for that @animuson.